# How to use GreenDAO to generate a Content Provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, greendao

Is there anywhere where I can find documentation for greenDAO Content Provider generation? I know based on [git](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src-template/content-provider.ftl) that it can be done but have no idea how to use it. [greenDao.com](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/) has all kinds of information there but nothing relating to the Content Provider Generator. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be generated [here in their source](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src/de/greenrobot/daogenerator/DaoGenerator.java#L70) and http://freemarker.org/ seems to be the template engine. Not sure if that's helpful in any way :)

Comment: @zapl What does 'ftl' in their source mean?  How does it map to ContentProvider object?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, looking at the source it looks to be just a file type. `.ftl`. It's used a lot for templates. I wonder if it just stands for Freemaker TempLate or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Each entity has its own ContentProvider for now, just call addContentProvider of your entities.

for example :

```
        Entity clientServer = schema.addEntity("ClientServer");
        clientServer.addIdProperty();
        clientServer.addIntProperty("tedadMorajeat");
        clientServer.addLongProperty("clientId");
        clientServer.addLongProperty("serverId");           
        clientServer.addContentProvider();
```

Comment: doesn't work for me.. I don't have the addContentProvider Function.

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by SMHJamali, adding the following line will generate ContentProvider classes for each entity :
`clientServer.addContentProvider();`

But  as [pointed out by greenrobot](http://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/149) the feature is not fully implemented yet.
If you want to see by yourself but don't see the `addContentProvider` function, you need to upgrade to version 1.3.1 `de.greenrobot:DaoGenerator:1.3.1`.

I suggest implementing a Contract class and using [ProviGen](http://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen) to generate the ContentProviders.